# How to transform a tibble to array?

Tags: r, arrays, tibble

Take `diamonds` data as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- diamonds %>% select(x, y)
```

There are `53940 rows` and `2 columns` of data; how to transform that  to an array with `[1:53940, 1, 1, 1:2]` dim?

Comment: Do you need `as.matrix`? But `dim(as.matrix(data))` is `c(53940, 2)`. Do you actually want a 4 dimensional array, like your dimensions imply?

Comment: Yes, the dimensional array is needed by other function. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) array** Use `data.matrix` and `array`:

```
a <- diamonds %>% 
  select(x, y) %>% 
  data.matrix %>% 
  array(c(nrow(.), 1, 1, ncol(.)))

str(a)
## num [1:53940, 1, 1, 1:2] 3.95 3.89 4.05 4.2 4.34 3.94 3.95 4.07 3.87 4 ...
```

**2) abind** Another approach is the `abind` package.

```
library(abind)

a2 <- diamonds %>%
  select(x, y) %>%
  abind(along = 1.5) %>%
  abind(along = 1.5)

str(a2)
## num [1:53940, 1, 1, 1:2] 3.95 3.89 4.05 4.2 4.34 3.94 3.95 4.07 3.87 4 ...
##  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
##   ..$ : NULL
##   ..$ : NULL
##   ..$ : NULL
##   ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"

identical(a, unname(a2))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi, please see the dim request in the question. Need to be `[1:53940, 1, 1, 1:2]`.

Comment: Hi, still not work. str(a) get `List of 107880 ... ` not as preferred: `num [1: 53940, 1, 1, 1:2] ...`

Comment: ```> diamonds %>% select(x, y) %>% array(c(nrow(.), 1, 1, ncol(.))) %>% dim          ##output##
[1] 53940     1     1     2``` This is what I get. It should be working now. @Zuooo

Comment: NO, it doesn't. `diamonds %>% select(x, y) %>% array(c(nrow(.), 1, 1, ncol(.))) %>% str [1] List of 107880 ...`

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, and patience.

Comment: Have added second approach.